# Excel formula for sales commision

Tags: excel

I have a sales engineer timesheet workbook with two sheets. The first sheet is titled 'Engineering Hours' and it has the following columns:

```
Date || PROJECT# || Office 1 || Office 2 || Commission
```

- The **PROJECT#** column will have data with a combination of letters and numbers such as JP1000
- The Office columns will have numbers associated with the number of hours of work performed on the specific date.
- The Commision column will indicate whether the engineering hours are pre-sales or post-sales, it will be blank for post-sales and have an 'x' for pre-sales.

I need a conditional formula, to put on a separate sheet within the same workbook titled 'Commision Total Hours', that will have two columns:

```
PROJECT# || Commision Hours
```

This sheet will:

- look for all the rows with an 'x' in the Commision column of the Engineering Hours sheet
- Populate the **PROJECT#** column with the **PROJECT#**
- Popluate the Commission Hours column with the sum of the numbers in the Office 1 and Office 2 column of all the rows with the same **PROJECT#** and the 'x' in the Commission cell

Ideally, this sheet will automatically add each unique **PROJECT#** only once, and it will automatically sort the **PROJECT#** column by the alpha-numeric values.

I've used the **SUMIF** command but only sparingly and have no idea how to make this happen! (or if it's even possible)

Comment: A formula can only update a single value of the cell it's entered in, it can't update an external cell with a value so this will have to be done via a PivotTable as suggested by @LS_dev or with a macro written in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel feature [PivotTable](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/overview-of-pivottable-and-pivotchart-reports-HP010342752.aspx).